# PHP error empty response

Tags: php, twitter, server, cloud

The php code below should work however, I receive an error, empty response, from my server.  Ive tried shutting down firewall but no luck.  Can you please help me I have been trying different methods for ages I have no idea whats wrongs. Thank you.

```
  <?php 
require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');

/** Set access tokens here - see: https://dev.twitter.com/apps/ **/
$settings = array(
    'oauth_access_token' => "",
    'oauth_access_token_secret' => "",
    'consumer_key' => "",
    'consumer_secret' => ""

);


$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json";

$requestMethod = "GET";

$getfield = '?q=cloud%20computing&count=5&result_type=popular';


$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
echo $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
             ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
             ->performRequest();


 ?>
```

Comment: `echo $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)` ? it should be a json response from twitter API, where do you use it ?

Comment: Hi, i was told to use it by this site, https://iag.me/socialmedia/build-your-first-twitter-app-using-php-in-8-easy-steps/.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> you need to use json_decode : http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');

$settings = array(
'oauth_access_token' => "xxx",
'oauth_access_token_secret' => "xxx",
'consumer_key' => "xxx",
'consumer_secret' => "xxx"
);

$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json";

$requestMethod = "GET";

$getfield = '?q=cloud%20computing&count=5&result_type=popular';
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$response = $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
         ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
         ->performRequest();

$string = json_decode($response, true); // there you handle twitter response
print_r($string); // here is the echo'd result, not needed after

// from here, you have access to the data
// then, a foreach loop will give you access to whatever you want to echo

foreach($string['statuses'] as $tweets) {
$tweet = $tweets['text'];
echo "<p>Tweet: $tweet </p>";    
}
?>
```

> updated with the loop example

Comment: Hi, sorry to bother you.  Thanks for the reply.  The code still doesnt work do you think its something to do with my aws server.

Comment: code works with my credentials... any error if you just copy/past my code ?

Comment: still not working I think your code is good I think it might be my server.  I tried it in firefox get this error message 'The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading', then in google its - error data did not send no response.  I don't know whether I need to do something to my server or not. thanks

Comment: Server does not seem that reliable though... can't you test on another one ?

Comment: no I cant I have a homework assignment and it has to be on aws linux.  I have no idea what to do.  Thanks for your help by the way.

Comment: Well as code works, I can't do much more... if helpful answer you can still give it a up :)

Comment: Hi there I got my server working.  Thanks for the help.  Can I ask you a quick question how do I go about repackaging this into a rss feed for html?  Thanks very much.

Comment: @winniethepooh : if answer was helpful, please consider upvoting it, and accept answer so that closes this topic. Then, open a new one with the new features :)